# Get Token from Client Email and Private Key (Service Account) in Google

Tags: c#, python, google-analytics, google-oauth

I have spent many hours trying to get a auth token.

I need to show to my users some Analytics information collected (I'm the owner of Analytics). I have created a Service Account, and I have tested all with this example, and all works fine (using the Nuget Package, of course).

Examples: [Link](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Analytics)

Code Example Working:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics}; // view and manage your Google Analytics data

var keyFilePath = @"c:\file.p12" ;    // Downloaded from https://console.developers.google.com
var serviceAccountEmail = "xx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";  // found https://console.developers.google.com

//loading the Key file
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential( new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) {
                                                   Scopes = scopes}.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

I have used Fiddler, and I can see how the token is "flying" between Google and my App, but I don't have any options to take it.

I need to do, something like this code on Python, but in C# to use [Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/)

```
# service-account.py

import json
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# The scope for the OAuth2 request.
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'

# The location of the key file with the key data.
KEY_FILEPATH = 'path/to/json-key.json'

# Load the key file's private data.
with open(KEY_FILEPATH) as key_file:
  _key_data = json.load(key_file)

# Construct a credentials objects from the key data and OAuth2 scope.
_credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    _key_data['client_email'], _key_data['private_key'], SCOPE)

# Defines a method to get an access token from the credentials object.
# The access token is automatically refreshed if it has expired.
def get_access_token():
  return _credentials.get_access_token().access_token
```

If you read documentation about Embed Api, you see that you need the token...

```
 /**
   * Authorize the user with an access token obtained server side.
   */
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': '{{ ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'
    }
  });
```

With all this information... How can I onbtain the service token??? Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me

c# code:

```
   public string bearer;
   GoogleCredential credential;

        string fichero = Server.MapPath("") + "//file.json";
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(fichero, FileMode.Open,   FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
        }
        credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[] { 
       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly" });


        try
        {
            Task<string> task = ((ITokenAccess)credential).GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
            task.Wait();
            bearer = task.Result;

        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
```

Javascript code:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
        'access_token': '<%=bearer%>'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking for something like this for 2 hours.

Comment: This worked for me also. Allowed me to go from a Service Account credential to an access token that worked in Postman,

Answer (score 1):

just to add to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218844/5334191, 
same in .netcore:

```
    public async Task<string> Token(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment webenv)
    {
            var root = webenv.ContentRootPath;
            var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, "googleanalytics.json");
            Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(file);
            credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[] {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly" });
            var result = await ((ITokenAccess)credential).GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
            return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're all good in creating your ServiceAccountCredential. What you need to do next is call `RequestAccessTokenAsync()` on your `ServiceAccountCredential` instance after which that instance will have it's Token property populated with the access token e.g.

```
if (await credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(new CancellationToken())) {
    var token = credential.Token.AccessToken;
}
```

You can then use that token in your javascript.